# Convert Negative Time Stored as Text

Tags: excel-2007

I need to be able to convert time values stored as text to number.  Those that have been stored as text appear to be negative values, in this format -0:03.  I need to be able to use these numbers in calculations.

Can someone advise how to fix as nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells that contain the *negative text time values* and run this small macro:

```
Sub ConvertNegativeTime()
    Dim r As Range, v As String
    Dim t As Date
    For Each r In Selection
    With r
        v = .Text
        If Left(v, 1) = "-" Then
            ary = Split(Mid(v, 2), ":")
            t = TimeSerial(ary(0), ary(1), 0)
            .Clear
            .Value = -CDbl(t)
        End If
    End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

If **A1** contains your posted value, after running the macro it would contain:

-0.020833333